# JQuery Isotope number filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I've been playing around with the isotope plugin and I think it's great!
However, it's only keyword based. What If I want to do some math filtering like adding a class: .age-35. Then, in my filter I want to select for example age > 30.
Is something like this possible or isn't this what isotope is designed for?
I've been trying to find some fiddles on the use of 'number filtering' but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort methods just need to return a number for each supplied element. It is called once for each element that needs sorting (i.e. the visible ones). What number it returns is up to your imagination.

e.g. You can extract attribute values from any part of the element (class, data-???, etc) and parse them into a number then return the number.